# how to fix We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect to server error while setting up trigger to build Jenkins job?

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to trigger Jenkins build whenever new changes are made in Github repo I followed this `video tutorial`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3S2gMBUkBo when I tried to redo exactly as shown in the video I get an error as We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect  to the server

this is my GitHub webhook configuration:
[image]

I tried to fix this error by doing this already given [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42037370/jenkinsgithub-we-couldn-t-deliver-this-payload-couldnt-connect-to-server) for this error using payload url as http://127.0.0.1:8080/github-webhook/, I cannot use ngrok tool as alternative.

I tried to open windows port as below steps:

1. Click Windows Firewall.
2. Click Advanced settings.
3. Click Inbound Rules in the left frame of the window.
4. Click New Rule… in the right frame of the window.
5. Click Port.
6. Click Next.
7. Click either TCP or UDP.
8. Click Specific local ports.
9. Type a port number. (In this case, open port 8080.)
10. Click Next.
11. Click Allow the connection.
12. Click Next.
13. Click any network types you'd like to allow the connection over.
14. Click Next.
15. Type a name for the rule.
16. Click Finish.

ater this refreshed github webhook settings and check for the connection again I was getting same error  We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect to server error
How to fix this? are there any other way to do this?

Comment: Hi, your url wouldn’t work as it's not publicly accessible. Where did you install Jenkins ? If your jenkins server has a public IP use that instead of 127.0.0.1 in the payload url

Comment: Hi brother, did you got any solution to this?

Comment: You cannot use 127.0.0.1 as a webhook URL because that is only accessible from the computer Jenkins is running on.  There is no solution besides using the correct webhook URL which is impossible to determine from the information provided in this question.